# Update one Array from another in a Function ('T_DOUBLE_ARROW' error)

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting a `(T_DOUBLE_ARROW)` error with the below function.

I'm trying to update the field `booking_number` from an array called `$details`. This is being updated from the contents of another array based on two arguments.

I get the feeling that it's something small and stupid. Think I've been staring at the code for too many hours!

Can anyone help? Would be much appreciated!

```
function addBookings($details, $bookings, $fulldate){
    foreach($bookings as $booking){
        if(($booking['class_id'] == $details['id']) && ($booking['class_date'] == $fulldate)) {
            $details['booking_number'] => $booking['booking_number'];
        }
    }
    return $details;
}
```

Comment: PLEASE DONT VOTE THIS DOWN - yes, it's a silly mistake, but unless you've had it before, it can be very difficult to identify - I've had similar problems where I've looked right at the problem, knowing it was the problem, but being unable to see anything but what I was expecting to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want there is `=`, not `=>`.

Comment: You're right it's that simple... *facepalm* I don't know how I missed it! Haha thanks though!